# Iterate over DOM elements in DalekJS

Tags: javascript, dalekjs

Does anyone know a simple way to iterate over, and operate on, all elements matching a query using the API?

My simplest use case is something like this - not real code, but hopefully you know what im looking for.

```
test.query('textarea').each(function(v, i){
  this.type(v.id, 'test' + i);
});
```

I can do it with arbitrary JS exec, jQuery etc. I just figure it's something that Dalek probably does that I've missed

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Turns out my JS exec backup doesn't work...

```
test
  .execute(function(){
    var textareaIds = [];
    (function($){
      $('textarea').each(function(){
        textareaIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
      });

    })(window.jQuery);
    this.data('textareaIds', textareaIds);
  });
```

But possibly due to the nature of how the code is queued then executed you can't use the array in a for loop afterwards. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

We are going to improve the API session in the upcoming version of DalekJS, so iterating over DOM elements & interaction between JavaScript executed on the client side & JavaScript executed on the server as part of the tests will be a lot smother.

Regarding your not working execute example. You can not just use the data passed via `this.data` in your Node code afterwards, you need to add it to the chain. As this is an very experimental feature, we did not really implement an API that can work with the data later.

One thing you can do, is abusing the `log.message` method like this:

```
.execute(// your code)
.log.message(function () {
  // get the data
  var myArray = test.data('textareaIds');
  // do something with it
  require('fs').writeFileSync('myFile.txt', JSON.stringify(myArray));
})
```

I suppose that this is not exactly what you want/need, but reusing that data for further tests and assertions is not yet possible. But we are working on it.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I was wanting to enter specific text into specific dom elements. Navigate away and return to test an autosave feature (just one example). Having read a bit of DalekJS I can see it wouldn't work. I'll be keeping a close eye on your v2 :) Good luck with it all